# Pydantic: Model dump of inherited model

Tags: pydantic

I want to extend existing Coordinates model with additional attributes.
Given this simplified example code:

```py
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel, SerializeAsAny
from pydantic_extra_types.coordinate import Coordinate


class Position(Coordinate):
    whatever: int


class POI(Position):
    name: str


class MainMap(BaseModel):
    positions: List[Position]


pos = Position(10, 20)
pos.whatever = 12

poi = POI(30,40)
poi.whatever = 10
poi.name = "exit"

mymap = MainMap(positions=[pos, poi])

print(f"Type of mymap.positions[0]: {type(mymap.positions[0])}")
print(f"Type of mymap.positions[1]: {type(mymap.positions[1])}")
print(f"Dump of whole model: {mymap.model_dump()}")
```

The output is

```
Type of mymap.positions[0]: <class '__main__.Position'>
Type of mymap.positions[1]: <class '__main__.POI'>
Dump of whole model: {'positions': [{'latitude': 10, 'longitude': 20}, {'latitude': 30, 'longitude': 40}]}
```

Why are the additional attributes, introduced in `Position` and `POI` not part of the dumped model, while the type of these list elements are correct?

I read about `SerializeAsAny` but didn't find a way to use this to get all information in the dump.

Further, are there any hints to de-serialize my model? In particular: How can I assure that instances of `POI`, `Position` and `Coordinates` are properly composed when loading the dump?

Thanks.

---

Edit based on @SUBASH THANGAM K's comment:

The version I set up based on your proposal looks like that:

```py
    from typing import List
    from pydantic import BaseModel
    from pydantic_extra_types.coordinate import Coordinate
    
    class Position(Coordinate):
        whatever: int
    
        def dict(self):
            return self.__dict__
    
    class POI(Position):
        name: str
    
        def dict(self, *args, **kwargs):
            original_dict = super().dict(*args, **kwargs)
            original_dict.update({'name': self.name})
            return original_dict
    
    class MainMap(BaseModel):
        positions: List[Position]
    
        def to_dict(self):
             return {'positions': [pos.dict() for pos in self.positions]}
    
    pos = Position(10, 20)
    pos.whatever = 12
    
    poi = POI(30,40)
    poi.whatever = 10
    poi.name = "exit"
    
    mymap = MainMap(positions=[pos, poi])
    
    
    dumped_dict = mymap.to_dict()
    print(f"Dump of whole model: {dumped_dict}")
    
    
    newmap = MainMap(**dumped_dict)
    
    print(f"Type of mymap.positions[0]: {type(mymap.positions[0])}")
    print(f"Type of newmap.positions[0]: {type(newmap.positions[0])}")
    print(f"Type of mymap.positions[1]: {type(mymap.positions[1])}")
    print(f"Type of newmap.positions[1]: {type(newmap.positions[1])}")
```

Now, the dump works correctly, but loading the model again, the 2nd element of `positions` is a position and not a POI anymore.
Is this the correct way to go?